# Create a newlist with elements of the sublists by my List

Tags: prolog

I have this list :

```
C = [[1,0],[2,3],[1,2],[1,3]]
```

I'll like find if the number 1 included in a sublist inside my list in position [1,_ ] and i like to save to a list Newlist the number of X ..... [1,X].

I will give an example... i have the list C and i am searching for sublist which first element it's 1 and give me the Newlist.

The Newlist must be : `Newlist=[0,2,3]`

It had the second element of the sublists who has the number 1 at the first element.

Comment: Can you show an attempt at the problem? Try first expressing logically what the solution looks like under different conditions. For example, if you call your predicate `select_list`, then you could say, "`select_list` of an empty list is empty".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[nth0](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=nth0/3)/3 allows to access list' elements by index:

```
?- C = [[1,0],[2,3],[1,2],[1,3]], findall(P, nth0(P, C, [1,_]), NewList).
C = [[1, 0], [2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 3]],
NewList = [0, 2, 3].
```

*edit* I'm sorry I didn't read the question right. nth0 is misleading. Could be instead

```
findall(E, member([1,E], C), NewList)
```

Comment: This answer is misleading and gives the expected answer by coincidence. There was nothing in the original question saying that the second element of the sublists will happen to also be the 0-based index of the sublist in the list.

Answer (score 2):

If you use SWI-Prolog with module lambda.pl, (you can find it at http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl) you can write

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

my_filter(V, L, R) :-
   foldl(V+\X^Y^Z^(X = [V,W]
           ->  append(Y, [W], Z)
           ;   Z = Y),
      L, [], R).
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a "filter". This is what it could look like:

```
filter_1_at_pos_1([], []). % The new list is empty when the input list is empty
filter_1_at_pos_1([[1,X]|Sublist], [X|Xs]) :- % The first element is 1 so the
                                              % second element belongs to the
                                              % new list
    !, filter_1_at_pos_1(Sublist, Xs). % filter the remainder of the list
filter_1_at_pos_1([[N,_]|Sublist], Xs) :-
    N \== 1, % The first element is not 1, ignore the second element
    !, filter_1_at_pos_1(Sublist, Xs).
```

As @mbratch suggested, just define the solution for one element of the input list for each possible condition, in this case 1) empty list 2) first element is 1 and 3) first element is not 1.

```
?- C = [[1,0],[2,3],[1,2],[1,3]], filter_1_at_pos_1(C, NewList).
C = [[1, 0], [2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 3]],
NewList = [0, 2, 3].
```

The cuts make the predicate deterministic. The cut in the last clause is not necessary.